# PHP - Streaming CSV Files to Browser

Tags: php, csv, download, export-to-csv

I'm having issues getting CSV files to download directly to my browser without storing the files somewhere on my server. I found a tutorial (https://www.perpetual-beta.org/weblog/php-stream-file-direct.html) but I can't seem to get it working!

This is my main function:

```
public function exportRecord($id) {
    $contest = (string) $this->getContest($id);
    $entries = (array) $this->getEntries($id);

    $filename = sprintf('%1$s-%2$s-%3$s', str_replace(' ', '', $contest['name']), date('Ymd'), date('His'));
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    ob_start();

    $header = array(
        'First Name',
        'Last Name',
        'Address',
        'City',
        'State',
        'Zip',
        'Phone',
        'Email',
        'Item Purchased',
        'Partner Name',
        'Partner #',
        'Date Entered',
        'Subscribe'
    );

    fputcsv($output, $header);

    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        fputcsv($output, $entry);
    }

    $string = ob_get_clean();

    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '.csv";');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

    exit($string);
}
```

I am calling the following two functions, which just do queries on my database...

```
private function getContest($id) {
    $query = sprintf(
        'SELECT name ' .
        'FROM contests ' .
        'WHERE id = %s;',
        $id
    );

    $result = $this->mysql->query($query);
    $response = '';

    if ($result) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $response = $row;
        }
    } else {
        echo $this->mysql->error;
    }

    return $response;
}

private function getEntries($id) {
    $query = sprintf(
        'SELECT firstName, ' .
            'lastName, ' .
            'CONCAT(address1, ", ", address2), ' .
            'city, ' .
            'state, ' .
            'zip, ' .
            'phone, ' .
            'email, ' .
            'itemPurchased, ' .
            'partnerName, ' .
            'partnerNum, ' .
            'dateEntered, ' .
            'subscribe ' .
        'FROM entries ' .
        'WHERE contestID = %s;',
        $id
    );

    $result = $this->mysql->query($query);
    $response = '';

    if ($result) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $response[] = $row;
        }
    } else {
        echo $this->mysql->error;
    }

    return $response;
}
```

I appreciate any help/advice that you'll give! Here is a screenshot, just to give you an idea of what the issue is: 
[image: Screenshot]
Thank you!

Comment: What type of browser are you using, exactly? I've recently found problems with Safari through this method.

Comment: I should have mentioned this! Sorry. I'm using the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox. I also tried it out on IE9.

Comment: Ok, 2 more questions.
1 ) Have you tried `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` to check if there are any errors? (place this at the top) - 2 ) do you get *any* results at all? Does the $string show anything? What exactly is not working?

Comment: My $string output looks good - but it's not downloading as a CSV file. ""First Name","Last Name",Address,City,State,Zip,Phone,Email,"Item Purchased","Partner Name","Partner #","Date Entered",Subscribe
Homer,Simpson,"123 Fake Street, Apartment B",Springfield,PA,12345,215-666-9876,hjsimpson@duff.com,JA12345,"Some Partner",987654321,"2015-01-01 00:00:00",
Steve,French,"123 Mustard Tiger Dr, ",Springfield,CA,76543,215-777-9876,stevefrench@trailerparkboys.com,JA12345,"Some Partner",987654321,"2015-01-01 00:00:00","

Comment: Could you try adding `header("Content-Length: " . filesize($string));` for me? I've heard that line makes a difference in some cases.

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/csv');`

Comment: Warning: filesize(): stat failed for "First Name","Last Name",Address,City,State,Zip,Phone,Email,"Item Purchased","Partner Name","Partner #","Date Entered",Subscribe

Comment: Using 'header('Content-Type: text/csv');' didn't have different output either! I tried that first (and retried just now).

Comment: I updated my exportRecord function - it's simpler now... but still not working. Thanks for all of the suggestions so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this with JS.

```
                    } else if (action == 'export') {
                    if (result.data !== false) {
                        var data = encodeURIComponent(result.data);
                        var contest = result.contest.trim();
                        var filename = contest + '.csv';
                        var dataUri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + data;
                        var link = document.createElement('a');

                        link.setAttribute('href', dataUri);
                        link.setAttribute('download', filename);
                        document.body.appendChild(link);
                        link.click();

                        showMessage('Export successfully created!', 'success');
                    } else {
                        showMessage('There are no entries for this contest! Nothing to export...', 'error');
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 7):

You are missing several steps from the sample by Jonathan Hollin. You need to start output buffering, you have to write the buffer out and set the headers correctly. This may need some modification but I tried to adapt the example to what you provided in this question:

```
<?php
public function exportRecord($id) {
    $contest = (array) $this->getContest($id);
    $entries = (array) $this->getEntries($id);

    $filename = sprintf('%1$s-%2$s-%3$s', str_replace(' ', '', $contest['name']), date('Ymd'), date('His'));

    $header = array(
        'First Name',
        'Last Name',
        'Address',
        'City',
        'State',
        'Zip',
        'Phone',
        'Email',
        'Item Purchased',
        'Partner Name',
        'Partner #',
        'Date Entered',
        'Subscribe'
    );

    export_csv($header, $entries, $filename);
}

private function export_csv($header, $data, $filename) {
    // No point in creating the export file on the file-system. We'll stream
    // it straight to the browser. Much nicer.

    // Open the output stream
    $fh = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    // Start output buffering (to capture stream contents)
    ob_start();

    // CSV Header
    if(is_array($header)){
        fputcsv($fh, $header);
    }

    // CSV Data
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        fputcsv($fh, $row);
    }

    // Get the contents of the output buffer
    $string = ob_get_clean();

    // Output CSV-specific headers
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '.csv";');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

    // Stream the CSV data
    exit($string);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I updated my code and tried this out in Chrome and Firefox... It's still not working. I have output ($string) in my Network tab when I Inspect the page. I uploaded an image.

Comment: Make sure all of the headers were set (Especially Content-Disposition & Content-Type). I've tested this again and everything looks good on the csv output stream side of things. It looks like you are casting an array to a string and such that is outside of the scope of this problem. I recommend creating a reduced sample to illustrate the problem more clearly. [link]https://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/